# Strange Pin Pierced Pipe in Boiler

Tags: boiler, central-heating, hot-water

Just wondering if anyone had any ideas on this?

The other day, I put the central heating on for the first time in about 6 months. The radiators did not get hot and within a few minutes the boiler started making a very high pitched noise and then the DHW feed pipe ruptured at a soldered joint and started spraying water. Upon further investigation the copper pipe leading to the DHW turbine/flow sensor appears to have some type of metal pin piercing the pipe from which water is also leaking.

I have had several plumbers look at it and they will be replacing the failed components but none of them can explain what the pin is, where it has come from or what the underlying cause of the failure is. They all say they've never seen anything like this before.

Can anyone identify this pin, why it was sticking out of the pipe and what may have caused this failure? I have attached images that might help.

The boiler is a Worcestershire-Bosch 24Si II

Many thanks for your help

[image: The Pin Piercing the Pipe]

[image: The Pipe that was Pierced (you can see the pin)]

Comment: it almost looks like a piece of a brazing rod - not sure how it would end up in your unit. might be worth writing to the company if it was inside... A.) even if they don't own it, they know where it came from, B.) the right level of disappointment and thoughtful professionalism they may offer an extended warranty or some other apology

Comment: Given the description on the problem sequence, I think the pin came out of (something) rotating at high speed, perhaps after breaking at the left end. I'd carefully examine anything in the direction it was stuck into the pipe from.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that pin shot out of the pressure relief valve.  If you look at the parts in your repair ticket it should be listed.